# How to solve the issue: "java: incompatible types: ...Project cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super ...Project>"?

Tags: java

While *building* the [project](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication), I'm constantly receiving the issue as:

```
java: incompatible types: com.test.application.data.models.Project cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super com.test.application.data.models.Project>
```

I have the following [Entity](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/data/models/Project.java#L18) class:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor 
@NoArgsConstructor 
@Entity(name = "project_entity") 
@Table(name = "projects") 
public class Project {

public Project(ProjectDTO projectDTO) { 
   this.name = projectDTO.getName(); 
   this.abbreviation = projectDTO.getAbbreviation(); 
   this.customer = projectDTO.getCustomer();
}

  @Id 
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
  @Column(name = "project_id") 
  private Integer id;

  private String name;

  private String abbreviation;

  private String customer; 
}
```

And I have `service` [implementation](https://github.com/invzbl3/RestApiApplication/blob/main/src/main/java/com/test/application/service/impl/ProjectServiceImpl.java#L28):

```
@Service
public class ProjectServiceImpl implements ProjectService {
  @Autowired 
  private ProjectRepository projectRepository;   
  
  @Autowired 
  private ProjectAdaptor projectAdaptor;  

  @Override 
  public List<Project> getAllProjects(Long projectId) { 
    return projectRepository.findAll().stream().filter(((Project) project -> 
project.getId() == projectId)) .findAny().orElse(null);
  }
  
  @Override 
  public Project save(Project project) {  
     return projectRepository.save(project);    
  }  

  @Override 
  public List<ProjectDTO> findAllProducts() { 
  List<Project> project = projectRepository.findAll(); 
    return projectAdaptor.databaseModelToUiDtoList(project);    
  }
}
```

Based on it my question is how can I solve the issue related to:

```
java: incompatible types: com.test.application.data.models.Project cannot be converted to java.util.function.Predicate<? super com.test.application.data.models.Project>
```

?

I'm ready to provide more details, if it helps.

I'm trying to get an `id` while rebuilding the project, but this error appears. I've researched some fresh information, but with no luck.

Thanks in advance for any help with it.

Comment: I suspect that because you have parentheses around your lambda expression, this expression is interpreted as being of type `Predicate`, because `filter` expects a `Predicate` argument. Try to change `((Project) project -> 
project.getId() == projectId))` into `(Project project) -> 
project.getId() == projectId`.

Comment: Generally speaking, reading **all** projects and then searching the list in-memory is a terrible way to implement this. Why don't you just call `projectRepository.getReferenceById(projectId)`? Also: your code (even when fixed), doesn't attempt to return a `List<Project>`, but a `Project` instead.

Comment: Well, or, more correctly, you have a lambda expression `project -> project.getId() == projectId`, which is inferred to be of type `Predicate`, but then you typecast it to `Project`.

Comment: Another problem: `projectId` is a `Long`. Comparing it using `==` is usually broken. Especially if `Project.getId()` returns an `Integer`. All in all: plenty of things are wrong here. I suggest you look for a sample how JpaRepository is usually used, as you may be using it wrong in multiple ways.

Comment: Thank you, guys, I'm testing now: ```projectRepository.findAll().stream().filter(project -> project.getId() == projectId.longValue()).collect(Collectors.toList());```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the lambda expressions in the filter you CAN express the argument type like this:

```
(Project project) -> ....
```

but it's really not needed here.

Not specific to the question there are two other points to fix here:

- doing `projectRepository.findAll()` and then filtering for id is a waste of resources, you'll load in memory ALL rows in that table and then discard all except one. Your `ProjectRepository` interface will probably has a `findById` method just for what you want
- the comparison `project.getId() == projectId` between two `Long` objects needs to be expressed using equals `project.getId().equals(projectId)`. You can use `==` if they where `long` primitive type and not objects.